What is a "hard-boiled turtle-slapper"?
Noir calls Tombstone

...you hard-boiled turtle-slapper.

What is a 'hard-boiled turtle-slapper'? Does it have any specific meaning?

It's supposed to be 1920s-style street-slang-from-another-dimension, but in reality is actually just meaningless nonsense.
It's possible that it wasn't even supposed to end up in the movie. It seems to have been an in-joke between the writers and the director to get the voice actor, Nicholas Cage to say funny rude-sounding lines, and somehow they decided to keep it, possibly because the original line was accidentally obscene.

ROTHMAN: We loved working with him. And obviously, he had fun with it. You do tend to over-prepare for Nic Cage because it’s kind of like “What would be funny to make Nic Cage say?” You end up writing an extra 20 lines just to like hear him say it even though you know it’s not going to be for the movie. In the movie…what does he say? “Biscuit-boxer”?. We literally had him record like 50 different weird slangs. Like, “You turtle-slapper”.
RAMSEY: A lot of them would have gotten us an NC-17 rating.
ROTHMAN: We literally had him record something and then it was in the movie…And then someone bothered to google it and it turned out to be a filthy, pornographic act, and we had to spend a lot of money.
PERSICHETTI: It wasn’t from the 30s at all.
'Into the Spider-Verse' Filmmakers Accidentally Made Nicolas Cage Say "Filthy, Pornographic" Things

